# Ubuntu 20.04 server ignores incoming postfix connections on IPv4, accepts IPv6

Tags: postfix, ufw, ubuntu-20.04

I've hacked my server to bits and now I need help.
Everything was working, but I *think* these issues started when I tried to add a VPN server to this server to test some items at work.  That process added fail2ban and a few other things.

When I check the mail error logs at /var/log/mail.err I see nothing at all. (the logs are blank)
/var/log/mail.log is writing, but I never see anything relevant to the emails that are being sent.
This is on all hosted domains.

I can not telnet to port 25 from outside the server, but I *can* telnet from the server to itself on port 25.  Postfix is listening on 25.

UFW has allow rules to allow 25/tcp and to allow Postfix on both IPv4 and IPv6.

This is a VPS running Ubuntu 20.04 and is regularly updated.

What can I supply to figure out where the problem is?

**Update 1:**
Results of iptables-save: https://pastebin.com/REywGKsq

**Update 2:**
I have found that test emails work if I connect via IPv6, but fail with IPv4.

**Update 3:**

results of postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 51200000
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = domain1.com, localdomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, domain2.com, domain3.com, domain4.com
myhostname = box.domain1.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
virtual_alias_domains = domain5.com domain2.com domain3.com domain4.com domain1.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Results of netstat -rn (IP addresses masked)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         AAA.BBB.CCC.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens3
10.8.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br-5e7471c33f48
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
AAA.BBB.CCC.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens3
```

Comment: Dump the whole iptables. There may be rules outside of ufw.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I've added a pastebin of the results.

Comment: Normally I'd suggest you don't post links or images to text you can copy and paste. However this is clearly a complete mess that you are not in control of. Change your fail2ban config to use ipsets. No VPN requires fail2ban. It will however change your routing tables which is the most likely cause here. Check your routing.

Comment: Can you please also dump your postfix configuration `postconf -n`

Comment: Another I would also enable logging in ufw. `ufw logging on` and then `ufw logging medium` and then `ufw reload`. You can then check the logs, maybe with a grep on the source ip if you see a block.

Comment: @symcbean I have set fail2ban to use ipsets (in jail.local) and reloaded.  I have also posted the results of netstat -rn

Comment: @Turdie I have posted the results of postconf -n and I have enabled ufw logging, but I don't readily see anything relevant there.

Comment: Can you check your network interfaces what kind of address they have assigned.

Comment: @Turdie The servers work fine for http and https using IPv4 and IPv6, so I think the network interfaces have the correct addresses types.

Comment: Can you also check your master.cf. `grep -E '^[^#]*inet[^6]' /etc/postfix/master.cf`

Comment: @Turdie results: `smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an iptables chain `FILTERS`

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j FILTERS
-A FILTERS -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FILTERS -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
-A FILTERS -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FILTERS -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FILTERS -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FILTERS -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

It allows only TCP ports 22,80 and 443 and rejects all other packets.
All your ufw chains on INPUT are inactive.

Comment: I used this command: `sudo iptables -A FILTERS -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT` and I can now connect to port 25 externally and mail testing tools appear to be working.

Answer (score 0):

the mynetworks parameter in your Postfix configuration seems to be incorrect for IPv4. It currently only includes localhost and IPv6 localhost, but it lacks a specification for IPv4 localhost.

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128  192.168.0.0/16
```

Replace 192.168.0.0/16 with the appropriate IPv4 subnet for your localhost if it's different

Comment: Wouldn't "localhost" cover "IPV4 localhost"?  Elsewhere in examples that I have found, only 127.0.0.8/8 is specified.  I have tried that to no affect.  This page: https://exampleconfig.com/view/postfix-ubuntu20-04-etc-postfix-main-cf shows the same setup as I have, which is apparently the default.

Comment: The hostname is something different than the network

Comment: I would rather go here for the configuration https://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#stand_alone

Comment: Thanks for all the help @turdie!  I really appreciate it.  AlexD's answer got me where I needed to be though.